# How to load a DEXT?

Tags: network, ethernet, driver, kernel-extensions

I want to use my MCX4121C 40GB PCIe fiber network card. I plugged it into my mac and connected it to another computer. However, it doesn't show anything. Then, I found that Apple's DriverKit extension `/System/Library/DriverExtensions/com.apple.DriverKit-AppleEthernetMLX5.dext` wasn't loaded:

[image: dext isn't loaded]

I can't find anything online about loading dexts. When I try to load it as a normal kext, it says:

```
> sudo kextload -b com.apple.DriverKit-AppleEthernetMLX5

Executing: /usr/bin/kmutil load -b com.apple.DriverKit-AppleEthernetMLX5
Error Domain=KMErrorDomain Code=71 "Kernel request failed: (libkern/kext) not loadable (reason unspecified) (-603946989)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Kernel request failed: (libkern/kext) not loadable (reason unspecified) (-603946989)}
```